# I am not able to make my enemy deal damage to the player once attacking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that detects when the player is nearby and triggers an attack animation for the enemy to deal damage to the player. However, I am running into issues getting damage dealt. I am using an event on the frame that the attack lands to call a pre-existing method called `takeDamage` from the player's script to reduce health but this doesn't seem to work and no change happens to the player's health. Below is the code for the enemy and the method for taking damage from the player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float attackCooldown;
    [SerializeField] private int damage;
    private float cooldownTimer = Mathf.Infinity;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask playerLayer;
    [SerializeField] private float range;
    [SerializeField] private float ColliderDistance;
    private Animator anim;
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        cooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (playerInSight())
        {
            if (cooldownTimer >= attackCooldown)
            {
                cooldownTimer = 0;
                anim.SetTrigger("meleeAttack");

            }
        }
    }

    private bool playerInSight()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = 
        Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center + transform.right * range * transform.localScale.x * ColliderDistance,
        new Vector3(boxCollider.bounds.size.x * range, boxCollider.bounds.size.y, boxCollider.bounds.size.z)
        , 0, Vector2.left, 0, playerLayer);

        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(boxCollider.bounds.center + transform.right * range * transform.localScale.x * ColliderDistance,
         new Vector3(boxCollider.bounds.size.x * range, boxCollider.bounds.size.y, boxCollider.bounds.size.z));
    }

    private void damagePlayer()
    {
        if (playerInSight())
        {
            playerHealth.takeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the method for taking damage:

```
    public void takeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        if (currentHealth < maxHealth && !_isPlayingAnimation)
        {
            maxHealth = currentHealth;
            anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
            _isPlayingAnimation = true;
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player has died!");
            anim.SetBool("isDead", true);
            _isPlayingAnimation = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `EnemyAI.damagePlayer` invokes `takeDamage`, yet nothing in `EnemyAI` actually calls/references `damagePlayer`. Post the relevant code, otherwise the question may be closed for needing debugging details.

Comment: And what is calling damagePlayer?

Comment: damagePlayer is being called using an animation event (i think thats what its called, sorry if thats incorrect) when the attack happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're reducing the players maxHealth to match the new health after taking damage, therefore the player's new health ist still 100%

```
if (currentHealth < maxHealth && !_isPlayingAnimation)
    {
        maxHealth = currentHealth;
        anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
        _isPlayingAnimation = true;
    }
```

currentHealth < maxHealth is always gonna be true (as long as your currentHealth cannot exceed maxHealth) and will reduce your maxHP everytime _isPlayingAnimation is false while taking damage.

To me it looks like you didn't meant to actually modify the players maxHealth.

Comment: This piece of code works fine for me, animation plays when hit and health is reduced accordingly, although it is a little scuffed because maxHealth decreases along with currentHealth but it doesn't affect its usage currently.